# How to validate two JSON objects present in a string

Tags: json, validation, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON String to validate which contains two separate objects. The string is `"1A"` but i want to validate it as individual objects for example: `{"NumberInt":1,"LetterThing":"A"}`.

In conclusion, my string is `"1A"` but I need to validate it as individual objects despite the fact it's in a string format.

Why do I want this? I have a minimum and maximum for the NumberInt integer value and I have a particular pattern for the LetterThing string value. For example: I do not want `"5H"` to validate.

If this is possible in a string format please let me know how.

Solved:
Was solved by using regex to validate on my JsonSchema i.e `"pattern": "^[A-Ja-j1-4\\s]*$"`.

Thanks guys

Comment: Hi, can you [edit] your question to provide a bit more clarity?  I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve (expected output) and what you've done so far to try to solve the issue yourself within `c#`

Comment: JSON is not just a fancy string format - it is serialized object data.  You could parse it or deserialize to get at the data inside.

Comment: Please note I'm validating against a schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract what you need from the JSON.

```
//obtains the number part, then you can perform operations on that number
var startingDigits = incomingString.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
```

Comment: You have a variable called `NumberInt` that is a string?  That does not seem like a good name.  Also another variable called `numberInt` that is different and only has a case difference in the name?  This is not best practice.  I made a few edits

Comment: Yes i solved it by using regex to validate on my JsonSchema i.e `"pattern": "^[A-Ja-j1-4\\s]*$"` and  `"maxLength":2` to ensure only 2 characters are present in my JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to PARSE the string in this case.

To parse a STRING you ITERATE over each CHARACTER in the string and then compose the needed parsed ELEMENTS.

For example in this CASE you might start looking for only DIGITS and putting them in another string.  When you hit a LETTER you can CONVERT that string to an integer.

Then take the REMAINING as the 2nd part.

Finally do your VALIDATION.